# Informatica powercenter Joiner Transformation

Tags: etl, informatica-powercenter

I am new to Informatica and I know it is very basic question.

It is advised that we should choose source with less number of rows as master and source with more number of rows as detail. Why so?

If I have 10 rows in Master and 20 rows in Detail then PowerCenter will create a cache of 10 rows and perform 10 iterations with 20 comparisons and if master and detail source are interchanged then it will perform 20 iterations with 10 comparisons in each iteration.

How is the performance improved in the former case, Is it because of cache size? Also doesn't Powercenter have to fetch data again and again from detail source to compare with master, If this is the case then shouldn't we be caching Detail source instead of master source?

Answer (score 0):

> If I have 10 rows in Master and 20 rows in Detail then PowerCenter
>   will create a cache of 10 rows and perform 10 iterations with 20
>   comparisons and if master and detail source are interchanged then it
>   will perform 20 iterations with 10 comparisons in each iteration.

I believe it is the opposite: in the first case 10 master rows are cached. So for each of the 20 detail rows it is compared with 10 cached rows. 20 iterations and 10 comparisons. In the second case, it is 10 iterations and 20 comparisons.

Although in both cases there are 200 operations, as the cache size in the first case is less, it is more efficient.

> Also doesn't Powercenter have to fetch data again and again from
>   detail source to compare with master, If this is the case then
>   shouldn't we be caching Detail source instead of master source?

No, PowerCenter will read every record only once from source and compare with the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add one thing to @Samiks answer: what happens if you join a huge and a ver small source? Lets's say it 10GB and 10MB.
So, you define the small one as Master. Once Powercenter session starts, it reads the 10MB into the cache. Then it starts reading the 10GB source row by row. For each one it gets data from the 10MB cache and sends the data to the Target without caching it. For the whole process only 10MB of cache is needed.